# change the position of jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery UI Datepicker.

However a vertical CSS scrollbar `overflow-y:scroll` causes a bug for Firefox, Opera and Safari.

This bug can easily be reproduced by copying the sample code of jqueryUI and adding 2 lines css declarations:

```
 body { overflow:scroll }
 #datepicker{ position:absolute; right:1px }
```

A demo can be seen [**here** (jsbin)](http://jsbin.com/obami/). To see the bug click at the textbox located on the upper right corner)

According to the jQuery team this bug will not be fixed as the body is customized.

Has someone been faced with this problem before?

Is there any solution to solve this issue?

Edit:

As seen in this screenshot it cuts a part of the calendar:

[alt text http://i37.tinypic.com/21awbo0.jpg](http://i37.tinypic.com/21awbo0.jpg)

Thanks
Jan

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I click the textbox a datepicker opens and a horizontal scrollbar appears as the datepicker doesn't completely fit onto the page. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Exactly that is my problem. I also added a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a clean solution as it looks different in Internet Explorer.

However it works and you might check for the users browser:

```
$("#ui-datepicker-div").wrap('<div style="position:absolute;left:-2em;top:-1em"></div>');
```

Comment: Similar fix suggested here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692601/jquery-datepicker-causes-page-overflow

Comment: Your question was asked one year after this one.