# jQuery datepicker causes page overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, overflow

I am using the datepicker control from jQuery-ui 1.8. `from-date` is a text input. I am attaching a very simple datepicker:

```
$('#from-date').datepicker();
```

This causes the page to overflow (vertical scrollbar), which I am trying to avoid. As soon as I click the from-date, the datepicker control appears, and the scrollbar dissapears. After dismissing the datepicker, the scrollbar doesn't appear anymore.

The text field is inside a div that has overflow:auto and a fixed height and width. I suspect it's a z-index issue.

What am I doing wrong ? How would I debug this ?

Comment: How about using $("body").css("overflow", "hidden"); to prevent the page from scrolling, if you never want it to scroll? Also, have you tested on multiple browsers?

Comment: In the end I will set the overflow to hidden for the entire body, but I would like to do so as a failsafe. First I need to find out why this is happening.
EDIT:
This happens in firefox 3.6.3, iexplore 8, opera 10.50

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to help if you provided the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. Wrapping Datepicker into a new div with a fixed position after the document is ready worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").wrap('<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;"></div>');
}
```

Comment: Great! This worked for me. I was using a data entry form in side a scrolling DIV. When scroll down and open date picker, the div scrolls up to the original position. Above solution fixed the problem.